# Using python to query Aure VMs by tags

Tags: python, azure, automation

I am not too versed with using Azure with python. I have searched online but can't find any resource to either query VMs using tags or using VM name, RG or ID to start/deallocate VMs in a loop. I am working with over 700 VMs.

Sample snippet

```html
try:
    vmlist = open("vmlist.txt","r")
 
    for vm in vmlist.readlines():
        values = vm.split()
        if OPTION in ['stop', 'deallocate']:   
            # Stop the VM
            print('\nDeallocating the VM')
            async_vm_deallocate = compute_client.virtual_machines.deallocate(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME)
            async_vm_deallocate.wait()
  
        elif OPTION in ['start']:
            # Start the VM
            print('\nStart VM')
            async_vm_start = compute_client.virtual_machines.start(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME)
            async_vm_start.wait()
 
        else:
            print('\nDoing nothing. Select either start or stop")
            exit()
            
finally:
    vmlist.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing existence of a VM by his name, would be just do a "get" and catch any exception as meaning "does not exist". If you want to be bullet proof, you can check that the exception is indeed a 404.

By tag, you must use the "azure-mgmt-resource" client, using the list ARM resources with a filter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#list

filter should look like (not tested, might need typo adjustements): `tagname eq 'mytag' and resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'`